# Как организовать через bash регистрацию на каком либо сайте?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, консоль

Есть shell скрипт , его задача такая :

Он спрашивает у пользователя номер телефона , пользователь вводит номер телефона , скрипт заносит номер телефона в переменную , 
и дальше скрипт должен регистрировать этот номер телефона на каком-либо сайте .

Грубо говоря , пользователь будет вводить рег.данные в скрипте , а скрипт уже будет сам производить регистрацию на каком-либо сайте . (регистрация через терминал(консоль)) .

Какие команды / пакеты посоветуете для реализации этой задачи ?

Comment: У вас задача создание бота, как я понял. Для этой цели лучше смотреть в сторону Python/Perl/Ruby у Python есть хорошие библиотке для обработки веб сокетов и парсеры выводов запроса. `BeautifulSoup; socket; requests; urllib`

Comment: в nodejs также есть все необходимые вам инструменты

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая разные сайты, разные методы регистрации - вариант использовать phantomJS.